# using firebase on offline networks

Tags: offline, firebase

I have a intranet network of 50 computers without an internet connection; is it possible to use firebase to share data across these computers - for example, a chat program? My limited knowledge in this field hints that this should be possible if the firebase api was downloaded to the local network and referenced with local expressions rather than web links - is this possible?
Thank you
Greg

Answer (score 0):

Firebase is a cloud service where all data is loaded from and synced back to the cloud. Currently there's no Firebase server that can be run locally, so it won't work without an internet connection.

Firebase does a very good job of punching through proxies / Firewalls though, so if you're concerned that your company's network connection might block it, I recommended at least giving it a try first -- it will probably work, unless you literally have no internet connection at all.